# Using Stagefright to stream small audio files in Android

Tags: android, caching, audio, audio-streaming, stagefright

I have a lot of small .ogg sound files (average size of ~35-50KB) that I need to have played from my AWS S3, and then once played, they need to be cached on the device.  There are approximately 200 sounds, and that is 1/10th of what the finished application will use.

I'm not sure the Stagefright library is my best bet, or if an entirely different approach is needed.  Should I use Stagefright, or go with another option???

Comment: Stagefright is the multimedia framework used _internally_ by Android. It's not something you access directly as an app developer.

Comment: Okay, so a different approach, then. I've seen some basic (and quite outdated information) on the NPR proxy library, does anyone have an updated idea on how it can work for this?

Answer (score 0):

From your query, I feel that you could use `SoundPool` for your application. Please refer to this link [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for more information.

A couple of examples can be found in [`MediaActionSound.java`](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaActionSound.java), [`SoundPoolTest.java`](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/cts/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/SoundPoolTest.java) and [`Soundclips.java`](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/packages/apps/Gallery2/src/com/android/camera/SoundClips.java).